# Python - tuple of unicode strings, encode error

Tags: python, mysql, macos, utf-8

I am using a stored procedure to get some rows from mysql databse.

I using very basic syntax:

```
retarr = []
cursor.callproc("employee_get", (-1, -1, -1))
for res in cursor.stored_results():
    retarr.append(res.fetchall())
cursor.close()
...
```

Now. Some of data results are unicode strings. I use UTF-8 for encoding string in my database.
I use charset="utf8" and use_unicode=True in my connection.

The problem occurs when i try to print any catched data (whole data tuple) which contain unicode characters.
Like:

```
for row in retarr[0]:
    print(row)
```

it prints me the first catched row properly. But the first has no unicode character. Then comes the second and all i get is an famous error:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u0119' in position 19: ordinal not in range (128).
What's the problem? I believe i am missing something very basic.

I use Python 3.3.2, standard mysql connector. OSX.

Comment: It might be your terminal system.  For example you can get `UnicodeEncodeError` on `cmd.exe` where it works fine in IDLE.

Comment: Strange, it might be a problem with Komodo, i use. If i try to print simply '\u0119' from terminal (python3) then it works, but running it from Komodo throws me that exception. I changed default enconding to UTF-8 in preferences, but it still does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in the PYTHONIOENCODING environmental variable.
When i set it in /etc/launchd.conf (file was absent on my filesystem) and rebooted my system all the problems gone away.

Comment: sure, i set it exactly to "utf-8". So it's
       "setenv PYTHONIOENCODING utf-8"

"utf_8" is not correct one. At least on my OSX (10.8.4)

Answer (score 1):

To print a unicode object, it needs to be encoded somehow. If your default encoding is ASCII, that will fail for anything outside of the 128 ASCII chars. You probably need to specify an encoding:

```
print(row.encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Ok, i thought, that utf-8 is standard enconding in python 3 unless one would customize it?

Comment: Besides, row is a tuple. It has no encode method. I need to figure out how to use utf-8 as default encoding in Komodo, beucase it seems that there is a problem.

Comment: Ah, you should have specified that row is a tuple. In particular, that means that when you print the object as a whole, it has the effect of calling `repr` on each of its members, which will certainly not encode properly. Try `print(','.join(i.encode('utf-8') for i in row))`.

Comment: Thanks, however i have mentioned that (whole data tuple). Anyway, problem was in my environment - at least correctig this fixes problem globally.